# Meaning of 賃料相当額

Tags: translation, words

I'm translating a lease agreement and I would like to know what does 賃料相当額 exactly refer to in the next sentence.

► 前項の規定にかかわらず、乙は解約申入れの日から30日分の賃料又は賃料相当額を甲に支払うことにより、解約申入れの日から起算して30日を経過する日までの間、随時に本契約を終了することができる。

► Notwithstanding the provisions of the preceding paragraph, by paying to the A party the rent for 30 days since the date of the termination request, or **the equivalent rent**, the B party may terminate this contract at any time within 30 days from the day of the termination request.

Context → 前項: 乙は、甲に対して30日前までに解約の申入れを行うことにより、本契約を終了することができる。

What does the "equivalent rent" refer to? I don't exactly know to what is equivalent this rent.

If you could help me, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Related: https://mbp-japan.com/okayama/tomisyo/column/3315154/

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, it's not a Japanese question but a legal one.

A rent is an amount of money paid in exchange for using the room or building. Therefore, after a fact that a person uses the facility ceases to exist for some reason, transferring money in the name of "rent" may lose its legal ground. In such case, one can describe it 賃料相当額 "rent equivalent" to ensure that the lender can claim the same amount as the monthly basis rent in case of early termination.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't know to what is equivalent that rent. In the sentence, it says "by paying to the A party the rent for 30 days since the date of the termination request, or the equivalent rent".

Comment: So, in case of early termination, you can "pay the rent for 30 days since the date of the termination request" or, which would be the other option?

Comment: I'd translate that part "the rent for 30 days, or the equivalent amount, since the date..."